# Border of multiple details tags in one html row are not working responsive

Tags: html, css, html-tag-details

I have a problem on my website: https://www.ars-neurochirurgica.com/ . I have several accordion menus which I made with pure css without any javascript and everything works perfect, except for one problem:

When I click on the categories to expand the tag, all other boxes which are collapsed with the detail tag which are on the same row will expand their border from the .div. Is there any way to fix this problem without using javascript? I tried to only draw the border if the details tag is open, however then I run into the problem that the border is smaller than the .div because it will be only assigned to the details tag. The best way would be to be able to select the parent element from the details[open] tag. However after doing some research that is not possible with css3 only. Anyone has ideas how to fix this problem? On mobile it works perfectly fine because only one row is displayed....

[image: illustration of the problem]

Comment: I can see you are using CSS Grid which means that each grid cell will have an equal row-height. Have you maybe tried flexbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick solution that just addresses the border issue you described:

1. Remove the `border`, `padding-left`, and `padding-right` from `.compactblock`.
2. Add the following CSS:

   ```css
   details {
       padding-left: 10px;
       padding-right: 10px;
   }

   details[open] {
       border: 1px solid var(--darkblack);
       height: 100%;
   }
   ```

Basically, this forces the `<details>` element to expand to fill the full height, so that its border surrounds the entire content of the expanded accordion block. It also moves the padding from the `<div>` container to the `<details>` element itself so that the width of the border matches the summary region.

**However**, since this approach still uses the `grid` layout, you'll notice that elements still "jump" below "phantom" blocks when you expand a block in any row. To resolve this, I would highly recommend taking a look at using `flexbox` instead, per the recommendation in the comments.

Comment: Thank you very much this basically solved my problem!!! I played around for such a long time and could not fix it, so thanks a lot! So using a flexbox would make my elements re-align and float properly if I open the accordion?

Comment: You'll need to do some fairly substantial reworking of your layout with flexbox, but yes, there should be a way. Alternatively, if you could somehow make the `<details>` elements top-level within the grid (without the `.compactblock` wrapper `<div>`), you could use `details[open] { grid-row-end: span [#] }` (where `[#]` is the appropriate number of rows to span; see [this example](https://codepen.io/balazs_sziklai/pen/mOwoLg)]).

Comment: Thanks a lot, since this is a small hobby project and I mainly care about the content of the website I will keep it like I have it right now since it's still quite usable and I will reconsider this if I will do a major rework of the website. Thank you so much you helped me a lot.